# Python 3.10 won't import modules

Tags: python, discord

I'm working on a basic discord bot in python, so after installing discord.py I start the code with `import discord`. The discord module is there, and when typing out `import discord` it will even autofill discord, and trying to install discord again just says that the 'requirement is already satisfied.' This is the case for both my devices (Windows 10 PC and a Macbook). When running it on my PC it runs perfectly, but when running it on my macbook I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Discord'`. The exact same thing happens with pygame, and probably other modules. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show the exact commands you used to install `discord` and run your program.

Comment: to install discord `pip install -U discord.py` in the terminal

Comment: to run the program: 
```import discord```

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. From the error message it looks like you're trying to import   `Discord` instead of `discord`.

Comment: I mean the call to `python` to start your program.

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installation on your machine? It might be the source of the issue

Comment: not 100% sure what that means, but i'm in pycharm so I'm just pressing the run button

Comment: i've tried both `import Discord` and `import discord` and neither work

Comment: I have both python 3.9 and 3.10 installed but only python 3.10 is configured in pycharm

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 versions of python installed then try:

```sh
# from https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/
# you must use `discord.py`
py -3.10 -m pip install discord.py
```

to install with `python 3.10`

Check the version by `pip -V` it must be using python 3.9 by default.